# Accessing news feed of facebook using restfb

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I want to access news feed of my facebook account. To do that I am using Java, RestFb.

I tried this code  :

```
private static final DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("", Version.VERSION_2_0);
    String queryString = "SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed')";
    List<JsonObject> objList=facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(queryString, JsonObject.class);
    System.out.println(objList.get(0));
```

But I am getting the following error  :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>       at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1309)
>       at facebook.newsFeed(facebook.java:32)
>       at facebook.main(facebook.java:36)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

I have one friend and i have already posted some pics and video.
also i can see the posts of my friend when i login to my facebook account on browser.

Please help me how to resolve this issue. so that i can see my news feed using restfb.

Comment: FQL is deprecated, and will go away on August 7, 2016. Don’t build anything new on it, use the current Graph API instead.

Comment: I tried :    **Connection<Post> myFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/feed", Post.class);
        List <Post> newsfeed = myFeed.getData();
        for(Post aFeed : newsfeed){
           System.out.println("Message : "+aFeed.getMessage() + " , Likes : " + aFeed.getLikes()+" , comments : "+aFeed.getComments() +" , Pictures : " + aFeed.getPicture());

        }**  but still i am not getting news feed of my friends .

Comment: And what do you get instead? What are the permissions that are connected to your access token?

Comment: I am getting only my own post. and I got access token for all fields at this time.

Comment: You don’t get posts by other people, unless those people also use your app, and have granted it permission to read their posts.